How to create AWS IoT thing using https call
There is API end point described in aws documentation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_CreateThing.html
But can't make it work, which prefix should i use and how to provide my account info to this endpoint?
I tried using data prefix with my iot certificates and got 404
Also i tried using control plane prefix with same certificates and got 403
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#iot-core-control-plane-endpoints

If you want to work with the AWS IoT service using API, use the AWS SDK and the IoTService client. There are examples.

As mentioned in my comment, to programmatically work with the IoT Service to perform tasks such as creating an IoT Thing, creating a cert, attaching a cert to an IoT Thing, etc, then use the IoT Service client. There are code examples located in the AWS Code Lib here:
Code examples for AWS IoT using AWS SDKs
To make sure you can get up and running, i suggest you start with this the Hello AWS IoT program that you can access here.
Hello AWS IoT

Thank you, using aws sdk will be much easier. But just for interest, is there a way to manually create thing through https request?

In theory - but i have always used AWS SDK to programmatically interact with AWS Services. Currently, for IoT, we have Java, C++, and Kotlin, if you would like to see other IoT languague examples, you can request that opening a GitHub issue - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues
